# Python Selenium webdriver loop with addition

Tags: python-2.7, loops, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Currently I am using the selenium webdriver to automate a reporting pull that occurs daily.

Basically, I am looking to repeat this code about 30 times for each report.  In addition I need to "press" the down key an additional time each time the code is run.  I hope I am giving you guys enough info with this.  If not, just ask - as always your help is GREATLY appreciated.

```
ProgramManagement= browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Program Management').send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN, Keys.ENTER)

browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ReportViewer1_HtmlOutputReportResults2_CSVButton_Content").click()
```

Comment: Its hard to help if we don't know what the problem is.

Comment: I am not sure how to use a loop to run this bit of code ~30 times.  Additionally, I am unsure how to increase number of down key presses on each loop pass.

Comment: As a sidenote, I recommend trying to avoid using those microsoft generated IDs seeing as they can change between versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of "key down"s can be increased by multiplication:

```
for report in reports:
    for x in range(0, 30):
        browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Program Management').send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN * x, Keys.ENTER)
        browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ReportViewer1_HtmlOutputReportResults2_CSVButton_Content").click()
```

Note the relevant `Keys.ARROW_DOWN * x` part.

Comment: Ok - this looks like what I need, however I am getting an error: 
undefined name: 'Reports'
Again, I am new so I am not sure what this means

Comment: @Yogwhatup the `for report in reports:` loop is just an example implementation of what you were describing "I am looking to repeat this code about 30 times for each report"..we don't know what you meant by that and improvised.

Comment: Works!  Thank you for all of the help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want something like

```
for report in reports:
    for x in range(0, 30):
        ProgramManagement= browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Program Management').send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN, Keys.ENTER)
        browser.find_element_by_id("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ReportViewer1_HtmlOutputReportResults2_CSVButton_Content").click()
```